# css text overflow and grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create in div 2 spans that once they fill the available space, they take 2fr and 1fr space... it has few rules:

1. if there's room, 1st span will fill the available space:

```html
<div>
   <span>longgggggggggg</span>
   <span>text</span>
</div>
```

result:

```
longgggggggggg text
```

2. if they overflow, they are seperated to 2fr and 1 fr:

```html
<div>
   <span>longgggggggggggggggggg</span>
   <span>textttttttttt</span>
</div>
```

result:

```
longgggggggg... textt...
```

3. if they are short, they float left (also, second part can fill rest, it is limited to 1fr only if first part fills the space):

```html
<div>
   <span>short</span>
   <span>textttttt</span>
</div>
```

result:

```
short textttttt
```

Comment: can you explain what exactly do you want?

Comment: I want the two `span`s fit in the div while overflowing

Comment: What have you tried so far, what is the width or max-width of that div ? to adapt the size of the span, one being twice the size of the other, or the other way round, or like you commented an answer eventually grow bigger . CSS cannot do this (2fr/1fr or ?? ). forget about the 2fr/1fr part and you might find something fluid enough ;) **- / -** here is a possible example that seems close to the question  https://jsfiddle.net/t7scwzL0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED IT WITH GRID!

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, max-content));
}

.first {
    grid-column: span 2;
}


span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
 
<div class="container">
  <span class="fist">short</span>
  <span class="last">text</span>
</div>
```

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the effect you're trying to do using `max-width` and `min-width`. I don't think you can use `fr`'s in this case but you can use percentage to achieve similar effect. You can try copying the code below and adjust the texts' length to see if it performs the way you want it to be.

```css
span{
  font-size: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
div{
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;        
}
.first{
  min-width: 33%;
  max-width: 66%;
}
.second{
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 33%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
        <span class="first">
Cumque iusto nisi inventore. Commodi, neque animi??</span>
        <span class="second">2nd text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime aliquid doloremque recusandae culpa exercitationem at quam, dolores atque sapiente nihil iste nostrum possimus, quibusdam molestias. Laudantium deleniti repudiandae aliquid voluptatibus!
Labore sunt neque laboriosam harum nulla. A itaque pariatur voluptate corrupti quos quia minima? Enim similique, itaque recusandae suscipit maxime facilis magni placeat ipsum quasi dolorem obcaecati dolores velit porro!
Fugiat maxime unde numquam nam esse ab. Similique maxime suscipit nihil qui vitae, quibusdam quae perferendis labore cupiditate laboriosam vel praesentium sed eaque adipisci dolor obcaecati eum? Nisi, ut corrupti?
Numquam esse voluptatibus ducimus quisquam sed aliquid sunt sit voluptatum, eaque adipisci quae ullam, odit obcaecati incidunt dignissimos, quasi cum prov</span>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: fixed the question to be clearer, both parts can get bigger than 66% or 33% if there's room

Comment: @eifr `width:100%` and `min-width` instead of `max-width` for the second class would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Flex.

```
<div>
  <span class="fist">short</span>
  <span class="last">text</span>
</div>


div {
  display: flex;
}
div > span {    
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
div > span.fist {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
div > span.last {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: fixed the question to be clearer, both parts can get bigger than 66% or 33% if there's room, so `max-width` is problematic

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve that with css.